# Are python Exceptions as class attributes a bad thing?

Tags: python, exception

I find myself often wanting to structure my exception classes like this:

```
# legends.py
class Error(Exception): pass

class Rick(object):
    class Error(Error): pass
    class GaveYouUp(Error): pass
    class LetYouDown(Error): pass

class Michael(object):
    class Error(Error): pass
    class BlamedItOnTheSunshine(Error): pass
    class BlamedItOnTheMoonlight(Error): pass
```

I have only seen this pattern used in Django (`DoesNotExist`) and it makes so much sense. Is there anything I'm missing, why most people seem to favor top-level Exceptions?

**edit**
I would use these classes for versatile granularity, e.g:

```
import legends

try:
    do_stuff()
except legends.Michael.Error:
    blame_it_on_the_boogie()
except legends.Rick.GaveYouUp:
    let_you_down()
except legends.Error:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    raise Hell()
```

Comment: How are you going to use these classes?

Comment: `raise Eyebrows("At Your Error Names", impressed=True, disturbed=True)`

Comment: Does you code make `BlamedItOnTheSunshine` subclass `Error` or `Michael.Error`?

Comment: `Error` gets overridden in the class definition scope, so it would be a `Michael.Error`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the exact pattern used by Django for certain ORM-related exceptions.

The advantage is that you can have an except clause which checks against a type accessed through an instance:

```
rick = Rick()

try:
   rick.roll()
except rick.GaveYouUp:
   never()
except rick.LetYouDown:
   never_ever()
```

This doesn't look that useful here, but if `rick` were a function parameter, then it would potentially be rather useful.

This is also extremely useful in writing generic code which raises the exceptions:

```
GoddamStar(object):
   def sing(self,tune):
       raise self.Error()

class Rick(GoddamStar):
    class Error(Error): pass
    class GaveYouUp(Error): pass
    class LetYouDown(Error): pass

class Michael(GoddamStar):
    class Error(Error): pass
    class BlamedItOnTheSunshine(Error): pass
    class BlamedItOnTheMoonlight(Error): pass

rick = Rick()

try:
   rick.sing()
except Rick.GaveYouUp:
   never()
except Michael.Error:
   never_ever()
```

Django's exceptions generally all derive from global base classes, so that you can also have a catch-all clause which still switches on a type of exception, in case your `rick` is of an unknown (or otherwise unprovided for) class.

The reason why this isn't much more common is that (a) it doesn't work in early-bound languages, which attract most of the book writers (b) it's moderately rare that this is useful to the user, and so application writers likely figure they aren't going to need it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Django, 1 more for style. I now realize that this is actually what brought me to this pattern. Still, I wonder why this is such a rare sight and people favor top-level exceptions.

Comment: @JessetheGame I've added a little bit on that point. Also, you can accept this answer if you wish.

Comment: No sweat, I was just waiting for some more depth on the downsides or rarity. Which you gave! And for icing we had a nice shoutout to Liskov.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to raise e.g. BlamedItOnTheSunshine outside of Micheal you would have to call it by raise Micheal.BlamedItOnTheSunshine('error text').

e.g.:

```
class A:
    class E(Exception): pass
    def __init__(self): raise A('error in A')

class B:
    def __init__(self): raise A.E('error in B')
```

in this Example A and B are not related, but if you have a relation like:

```
class Interpret(object):
    class LetsYouDown(Exception): pass
    def __init__(self): raise self.LetsYouDown("I'm not Rick!")

class Michael(Interpret):
    class BlameItOnTheSunshine(Exception): pass
    def __init__(self): raise self.BlameItOnTheSunshine("It's not the Moon!")

class Rick(Interpret):
    class NeverEver(Exception): pass
    def __init__(self): print "Never Ever!"

and want now something like:
    try:
        for superstar in [Interpret, Michael, Rick]:
            star_in_show = superstar()            
    except superstar.LetsYouDown:
        print "Where's Rick?"
    except superstar.BlameItOnTheSunshine:
        print "Must be Michael!"
```

you will get an Error i would call a Liskov's Principle violation.
So one of the main reason's (polymorphism) for using OOP  is somewhat compromised. But it
doesn't necesarrily mean you can't or shouldn't use it. Just be aware of the limitations.

i hope that cleared my initial cryptical reservations up.

Comment: You can still access them as `Michael.Error`, etc.

Comment: That is exactly the merit I see in using this.

Comment: +1 for Liskov. It can be overcome though, by having the generic `Error` class inherit from each `Error` class of its direct parents. That could potentially turn in to chaos though, when the parent Errors do stuff.